# Windows 7 - HP Z840 with 256 GB RAM

Tags: windows-7, memory

I'm planning to buy a HP Z840 Workstation with 256 GB RAM (8 x 32 GB).
I know that the memory limit of Windows 7 is 192 GB, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778(v=vs.85).aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_7.

Is it possible to install and run Windows 7 on a PC with more than 192 GB of RAM? Even if I could just use 192 GB of my 256 GB.

I'm aware that Windows 10 supports up to 2 TB of RAM. There are other stupid reasons why this machine has to run under Windows 7.

Comment: "Is it possible to install and run Windows 7 on a PC with more than 192 GB of RAM?" Why don't you try it and see if it works? Then answer your own question.

Comment: Because: `I've a HP Z840 Workstation with 256 GB RAM` is not true. At the moment we have a Z820 with 192 GB and we're planning to buy another Z840 with 256 GB of RAM (8 x 32 GB). And I want to know if this would be a problem. We can switch to Windows 10 in about a year.

Comment: "HP Z840 Workstation with 256 GB RAM is not true" well I don't suppose many people here have such a workstation either ...

Comment: You can always install the OS, it just won't let you use all the RAM.

Comment: @Appleoddity: Do you've any reference which claims that?

Comment: Anyway I think I'll order that workstation and try it. In the worst case I could physically remove 2 x 32 GB of RAM.

Comment: This is just my experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the mean time I've received my Z840 with 256 GB of RAM and so I was able to test it.

Yes it's possible to install and run Windows 7 on a PC with more than 192 GB of RAM. See the following screen shot.

[image: Control Panel / System and Security / System]

Comment: +1 for the follow up.  Have you found a way to utilize the remaining RAM as your screenshot says only 192GB is usable?

Comment: @Damon No. I'll wait until our IT departement is ready to switch to Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you still can run Windows 7 64 Bit on this WorkStation with 256GB (8 x 32GB LRDIMM). 192GB will be recognized, rest will be ignored. But it is better to have the non-addressable memory or install in 3x32GB + 3x32GB for the best performance.

To have non-addressable/ignored memory in the workstation for longer periods is not recommended.